# How to traverse through dictionary with lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have dictionary that represents tree without weights:

```
dict = {1: [1, 3], 2: [2, 3], 3: [3, 5], 4: [4, 5], 5: [2, inf], 6: []}
```

It contains only integers.
I want to print out path from the key that contains 'inf' like this:

```
 5-2-2-3-3-5
```

[image]

What is the easiest way to do it? If using while loop, what statement should it have?

Comment: your dict seems to have the only int as keys. may be you need to update your question and explain it again.

Comment: @shivank98 updated

Comment: @appendix in your figure, why does 6 connect to 2?

Comment: @Graeme Yes, my mistake, it shouldn't be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three things to accomplish this:

1. A store of how many times you've visited a particular index
2. A method of translating the information in 1 into the proposed next key to visit
3. You need to repeat this procedure while your next key is in your dict.

---

Possible implementation:

```py
dict = {1: [1, 3], 2: [2, 3], 3: [3, 5], 4: [4, 5], 5: [2, 'inf'], 6: []}

visit = {}
path = []
next_key = 5
while next_key in dict:
    this_key = next_key
    path.append(this_key)
    try:
        next_key = dict[this_key][visit.setdefault(this_key, 0)]
        visit[this_key] += 1
    except:
        break

# Result
print(*path, sep='-')
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!